# Why do I get different sort order of the same query executed in Teradata & Snowflake?

Tags: sorting, sql-order-by, teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, resultset

I am getting different sort order even if I have added order by clause in both the queries.
Here are queries that I am executing on Teradata & snowflake-

Teradata :

```
Select column1, column2, column3, column4,column5 From Teradata_Table  Where column1 in (1027837724,1040965189,1046224751) and column2='2021-03-11'
order by column1 ;
```

Result -->

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1027837724 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 42.66 | 5942 |
| 1027837724 | 3/11/2021 | 12052.34 | 2.99 | 5735 |
| 1040965189 | 3/11/2021 | 5336.72 | 10.87 | 5944 |
| 1040965189 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 311.16 | 5942 |
| 1046224751 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 14.99 | 5735 |
| 1046224751 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 2.99 | 5735 |

Snowflake :

```
Select column1, column2, column3, column4,column5 From Snowflake_Tablename  Where column1 in (1027837724,1040965189,1046224751) and column2='2021-03-11'
order by column 1
```

Result -->

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1027837724 | 3/11/2021 | 12052.34 | 2.99 | 5735 |
| 1027837724 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 42.66 | 5942 |
| 1040965189 | 3/11/2021 | 5336.72 | 10.87 | 5944 |
| 1040965189 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 311.16 | 5942 |
| 1046224751 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 14.99 | 5735 |
| 1046224751 | 3/11/2021 | 0 | 2.99 | 5735 |

Comment: You are only specifying a single order by column. You have multiple rows with the same value in that column, so the sorting within that is basically random.

Comment: Yes. Order *within* a group of rows with equal ORDER BY columns isn't even guaranteed to be the same if you run the query twice on the same DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say:

- You are only sorting by one column, and the order of the rows ordered by that column is the same regardless of database.
- But you are not asking the database to sort by any other column, so rows that have the same column1 can be presented in any arbitrary order.

If you want to make the order consistent, you should `ORDER BY column1, column2, column3, etc`.